# Remove initial spacing on a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, parskip

How do I decrease the vertical space at the beginning when a new paragraph is started?

For example, you can see the second paragraph, started with `\paragraph{}` has extra spacing that I need to change..!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\paragraph{}
\kant[2]
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need `\paragraph` in order to start a paragraph. The command name was badly chosen, but it denotes a document division (below `\subsubsection` in the hierarchy). Just leave a blank line when you want to start a paragraph.

Comment: `\paragraph` is a 4th level section heading and should only be used in the sequence section.subsection,subsubsection,paragraph. it is _not_ for making paragraphs of text, for that just use a blank line

Comment: the space is needed to separate the heading from the text try with the intended use `\paragraph{my para heading}` you need a space after `heading`

Comment: what happens if you add some text behind `\paragraph{}` (not _blind text_ block

Comment: @TimothyTruckle it's the same of course:-)

Comment: The control sequence that you are looking for is `\parskip`. Note that many times this length is not set to a a constant value as `1em` but a glue as  `1em plus .2em minus .2em`. See also the `parskip` package.

Comment: tried parskip, but that only changed the subsequent paragraphs, not the initial one...